# MTLRenderPipeline Print an Error Message

Tags: metal

This is the error message:

**/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-55.2.6.1/Framework/MTLRenderPipeline.mm:1006: failed assertion `Blending is enabled for render target 0; however, the pixelformat MTLPixelFormatRGBA32Float for this render target is not blendable.'**

The stacktrace show in xcode is:

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0 0x230e5c84 in __pthread_kill ()
#1 0x23187b46 in pthread_kill ()
#2 0x2307c0c4 in abort ()
#3 0x2305b8b6 in __assert_rtn ()
#4 0x24e13f64 in MTLReportFailure ()
#5 0x24e133ac in -[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:] ()
#6 0x0a65c30e in ___lldb_unnamed_function437$$AGXMetalG5 ()
#7 0x0a66c20c in ___lldb_unnamed_function555$$AGXMetalG5 ()
#8 0x010e6a70 in GfxDeviceMetal::GetPipeline(GfxDeviceMetal::PipeKey const&) at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/metal/GfxDeviceMetal.mm:182
#9 0x010e82c4 in GfxDeviceMetal::SetupMetalPipeline(MetalVertexDecl const*, ChannelAssigns const&) at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/metal/GfxDeviceMetal.mm:729
#10 0x010e1394 in MetalVBO::DrawVBO(ChannelAssigns const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, GfxPrimitiveType, unsigned int, unsigned int) at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/metal/BuffersMetal.mm:251
#11 0x00de9614 in DrawUtil::DrawVBOMeshRaw(VBO&, Mesh&, ChannelAssigns const&, int, unsigned int) at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Graphics/DrawUtil.cpp:37
#12 0x00de965c in DrawUtil::DrawMeshRaw(ChannelAssigns const&, Mesh&, int) at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Graphics/DrawUtil.cpp:47
```

I cannot understand what is the meaning And how to fix the problem.

**THANKS**

Comment: From parsing the error message, you would either need to disable blending on the primary color attachment of the render pass descriptor, or use a pixel format for the primary color attachment's texture that is blendable, such as `MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm`. Without knowing your use case, it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: Note: I should have said "render pipeline descriptor" rather than "render pass descriptor."